# Fastest way to retrieve a list of every VMs DNS Host Name?

Tags: powershell, dns, virtual-machine, powercli

I would like to find the fastest and simplest way to get a list of every VMs DNS Host Name on the system. To then use this list of data for other purposes. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your question doesn't go into much detail or contain any of the code you are using. Check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question that will get you a good answer.

Comment: Are you on Vcenter/HyperV or just somewhere on the network? Do you have a list of machines or subnets to scan or do you do that dynamically? Have you tried anything at all before deciding to subscribe to Stack Overflow's Free scripting services?

Comment: I am a bit new to dealing with powershell, and wasn't sure. Using a VCenter, don't have a list of machines so will do dynamically. Tried get-vm for each machine but was quite slow as have many machines so was hoping for a more stream lined command for the info i needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Get-VM | Select Name,@{N="DNS Name";E={$_.Guest.HostName}},@{N="IP Address";E={$_.Guest.IPAddress}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = Get-View -Viewtype VirtualMachine -Property guest.hostname, name 
$list | Select-Object -Property name, @{Name = 'DNSHostname'; Expression = {$_.guest.hostname}} | sort-object version
```